# Push to the next table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, rows

I have two table views containing data, the first one is completely okay. I want to push from this table view to another view to another table view, but I cannot set the rows for it. How can I navigate through a multidimensional array in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Basically, my problem is about setting the right text for a row and getting from a multidimensional array :) (P.S. I have a different number of Strings in each subarray)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check on which tableView you are setting the values.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  if tableView == myFirstTableView {
    // put the data for the first tableView
  } else {
    // put the data for the second tableview
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not helping. I am using it for only one table view, the other table view's rows are set in another file.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, I put one of my functions into a wrong file :)